# How to remove last N chars from a string column in python-polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"s": ["pear", None, "papaya", "dragonfruit"]})
```

I want to remove the last X chars, e.g. remove the last 2 chars
from the column.
This obviously doesn't do what I want:

```
df.with_columns(   
    pl.col("s").str.slice(2).alias("s_sliced"),

)
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────┬──────────┐
│ s           ┆ s_sliced │
│ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ str         ┆ str      │
╞═════════════╪══════════╡
│ pear        ┆ pe       │
│ null        ┆ null     │
│ papaya      ┆ papa     │
│ dragonfruit ┆ dragonfru|
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex with [`.str.replace`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.replace.html#polars.Expr.str.replace)

- `.` matches a "single character"
- `$` matches the "end"
- `{N}` matches exactly N times

Meaning we could use `..$` or `.{2}$`

```
df.with_columns(   
    pl.col("s").str.replace(r"..$", "").alias("s_sliced"),
)
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────────┐
│ s           ┆ s_sliced  │
│ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ str         ┆ str       │
╞═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ pear        ┆ pe        │
│ null        ┆ null      │
│ papaya      ┆ papa      │
│ dragonfruit ┆ dragonfru │
└─────────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex way to do this is pretty ugly but here it is...

```
df.with_columns(
    s_sliced=(pl.col('s').str.explode().implode().over('s')
                .list.take(pl.arange(0,(pl.col('s').str.n_chars()-2))))
            .list.eval(pl.element().str.concat("")).list.get(0))
```

The first thing to notice is that we're converting the character column into a list using `str.explode.implode`, this is because `str.slice` doesn't take an expression for the length but `pl.arange` does. Then we just use take the elements we want which is all over them except the last 2 Lastly, we have to convert our list back into a string.

** There was a really concise answer using a simply regex but its author deleted it and I'm reluctant to copy it. Maybe the post's author will undelete it.

Comment: Thanks Dean - after a rethink, I wasn't sure if suggesting regex was the correct approach.

Comment: @jqurious yeah in base python, as I'm sure you know, you could just do `s[0:-2]` but the polars slice isn't as flexible so regex is certainly the easiest to read. There was [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7127) issue a while back which is similar but for lists

Comment: Thanks for the issue link. Yeah, I thought perhaps a `.str.head` / `.str.tail` might exist to mirror the other head/tail functions.